# Query to JOIN / *overwrite* field

Tags: sql, join

I'm not sure if I'm using the correct terminology.

```
SELECT movies.*, actors.`First Name`, actors.`Last Name`
From movies
Inner Join actors on movies.`actor1` Where movies.`actor1` = actors.`indexActors`;
#Inner Join actors on movies.`actor2` Where movies.`actor2` = actors.`indexActors`;
```

I have the 2nd line commented out, each one works individually, and I'm wondering how to combine them.

2ndly, when I execute the query, I get the results:

```
ID  Title                   Runtime Rating  Actor1  Actor2  First Name Last Name
1   Se7en                   127     R       1       2       Morgan     Freeman
2   Bruce Almighty          101     PG-13   1       3       Morgan     Freeman
3   Mr. Popper's Penguins   94      PG      3       4       Jim        Carrey
4   Superbad                113     R       4       5       Emma       Stone
5   Crazy, Stupid, Love.    118     PG-13   4       Null    Emma       Stone
```

Is there a way to add the results from the 2nd join to the rightmost columns?
Also, is it possible to combine the strings/VARCHARs from First Name and Last Name, and then have that value show up under the corresponding Actor Field?
(aka the field under Actor 1 for row 1 would be "Morgan Freeman" instead of "1")

Thanks.

Comment: depend on your db ...http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: SELECT movies.*, actors.`First Name`, actors.`Last Name`,actor2.firstname||actor2.lastname...  try...look for union too

Comment: The sql you posted is not valid.  Are you sure it works?

Answer (score 0):

Your sql is not valid, but you can achieve your goal by joining to the same table twice, with different aliases.  This sort of thing

```
select blah blah blah
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.field1 = t2.field1
join table2 t2_again on t1.field1 = t2_again.field2
etc
```

As far as joining first and last names in a single field, most databases have a way to concatenate strings, but they are not all the same.  You'll have to specify your db engine.